# Better to add extra bones before or after generate rig

Tags: rigging, drivers, shape-keys, rigify

Im using rigify addon and plan to add some shape keys and some drivers later on like for facial expressions and talking. Is it a good idea to add those driver bones to the metarig before I click generate rig or should I generate the rig and then later on edit the new rig by adding more bones?